# Efficient SQL Query to calculate portion of a row in half hourly time series that has occurred

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | slot | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-01T12:00 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01T12:30 | 150 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01T13:00 | 200 |

There's an index on slot already. The table has ~100mil rows (and a bunch more columns not shown here)

I want to sum the total up to the current moment in time **(EDIT: WASN'T CLEAR INITIALLY, I WILL PROVIDE A LOWER SLOT BOUND, SO THE SUM WILL BE OVER SOME NUMBER OF DAYS/WEEKS, NOT OVER FULL TABLE)**. Let's say the time is currently `2022-12-01T12:45`. If I run `select * from my_table where slot < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`,
then I get back records `1` and `2`.

However, in my data, the records represent forecasted sales within a time slot. I want to find the forecasts as of `2022-12-01T12:45`, and so I want to find the proportion of the half hour slot of record `2` that has elapsed, and return that proportion of the total.

As of `2022-12-01T12:45` (assuming minute granularity), `50%` of row `2` has elapsed, so I would expect the total to return as `150 / 2 = 75`.

My current query works, but is slow. What are some ways I can optimise this, or other approaches I can take?

Also, how can we extend this solution to be generalised to any interval frequency? Maybe tomorrow we change our forecasting model and the data comes in sporadically. The hardcoded `30` would not work in that case.

```
select sum(fraction * total) as t from
 select total,
        LEAST(
   timestampdiff(
   minute,
   datetime,
   current_timestamp()
    ),
   30
) / 30 as fraction

  from my_table
  where slot <= current_timestamp()
```

Comment: 'I want to sum the total up to the current moment in time.' - from when? start of day, start of month, start of year??

Comment: 'Maybe tomorrow we change our forecasting model and the data comes in sporadically.' - preempting al possibilities is a fruitless exercise..

Comment: Pre-empting very likely possibilities is a prudent exercise. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider computing your sum first, then remove the last element partial total. In order to keep the last element total, I'd prefer applying window functions instead of aggregations, and limit the output to the last row.

```
SET @current_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT slot, 
           SUM(total) OVER(ORDER BY slot) AS total,
           total                          AS rowtotal
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE slot < @current_time
    ORDER BY slot DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT slot, 
       total - (30 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
                                   slot,
                                   @current_time))
               /30 * rowtotal AS total
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7NUzVYssgQv92Ff7pLEyYp/1).

**Note1**: Adding an index on the slot field is likely to boost this query performance.

**Note2**: If your query is running on millions of data, your timestamp may be likely to change during the query. You could store it into a variable before the query is run (or into another cte).

Comment: I think your calculation for the fraction is time elapsed, not time remaining. Shouldn't it be `total - (30 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, slot, @current_time)) / 30 * rowtotal AS total`? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s6qV0_Lk)

Comment: It's the time we're removing from, you're definitely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really like the approach of capturing the total and the row total, and subtracting. Exactly the type of efficiency I was looking for!